# stored procedure float parameters being split into two int parameters

Tags: c++, sql-server-2008, visual-c++

As I'm calling a stored procedure from a C++ code my float parameters somehow are split like this: 34.555 => 34,555, and an error arises as the number of parameters mismatch.

This is how I add parameter to _CommandPtr

```
    ... 
    VARIANT VtLon = {0};
    VtLon.vt = VT_NULL;

    if(TargInf.dwFields & TI_FIELD_LON )
    {
        VtLon.vt = VT_R8;
        VtLon.dblVal = TargInf.dLongitude;
    }
    param = pCommand_LogNewEvent->CreateParameter( _bstr_t( L"lon" ), adDouble, adParamInput, sizeof( double ), VtLon );
    pCommand_LogNewEvent->Parameters->Append( param );
    ...
```

I changed the sql server Default Language from Russian to English and the problem was gone.
But I need a way to manage it without such a global setting.

Comment: Added C++ tag. Always use this tag for C++ questions, to get more answers.

Comment: The underlying problem is that SQL is basically a language from the sixties, and is stringly typed. In a stringly typed language, input needs to be parsed. And this parsing is locale-dependent, which means it breaks when you cross locales. (This is also why you have SQL injection attacks, but no ISAM injection attacks)